# Sharepoint new page help

Tags: 2013, development

I am new here and new to 2013, i need to create a simple webpage in Sharepoint to look like an existing HTML page that we had hosted on another webserver.

Can anyone please help me with this? what APP should i use? i was looking at using the announcements app and adding each section in but the client thought it looked too much like a table?????
[image]

I do not have the HTML Code for the old site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Designer.

Make a note - SharePoint uses Master Page and Page Layouts. It uses its own CSS. So you need to make sure the styles you are using in your HTML page is not getting affected by those.

Comment: Thanks for this, i do not have the HTML content, all that i have is the JPG of the webpage. so ill need to start from scratch.